# Bootstrap nav bar menu icon not displaying

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstraps nav bar and I have set menu icon and when i make the browser screen smaller the nav bar works, however, the icon does not display.

HTML:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#stats">Stats</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>

CSS:
.navbar-toggler-icon: {
    background: url(../img/icons/menu.png);
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh2LK.png)

Answer (score 1):

check your image url path and use quotes like `background: url("../img/icons/menu.png");`

or try this as alternative

```
background-image: url("../img/icons/menu.png");
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This didn't seem to work though.